# Adding cookies to drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drag-and-drop, position

I'm creating an drag and drop plugin and I thought to make it a little unique i would add a cookies feature to save the position of the dragged elements.

I'm currently using the following code for the get and set cookies:

```
$.setCookie = function(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
$.getCookie = function(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

These work fine. But What I can't get to work is this:

```
if (o.cookies === true) {
    $(oj).mouseup(function() {
        var currentPos = $(oj).position();
        $.setCookie('tposition22' + $(oj).index(), currentPos.top, 365);
        $.setCookie('lposition22' + $(oj).index(), currentPos.left, 365);
        alert('Cookies Set!')
    });
    $(function() {
         var savedLeftPosition = $.getCookie('lposition22' + $(oj).index());
         var savedTopPosition = $.getCookie('tposition22' + $(oj).index());
         $(oj).css({
             top: savedTopPosition,
             left: savedLeftPosition
         });
    });
}
```

Code Description: `o.cookies === true` is to check if cookies is set to true; setCookie works(I checked); `oj` is referring to `this`, the selector.

Problem: I need to be able to get the value of the cookie. Because, im currently trying to make the value the position of the dragged element and then retrieving it.

As you can see in `$.setCookie('tposition22' + $(oj).index(), currentPos.top, 365);`, `currentPos.top` is in the value spot. To get the Y position of the dragged element.

**Main Question:** Is there a way to retrieve the `value` of a cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can retrieve the value of a cookie. I like not reinventing the wheel, though, and since you're already in jQuery-ville, why not use a jQuery cookie plugin? I think there's even an "official" one. Should provide simple access to everything you need for interacting with cookies (really, just getting and setting one!).

With regard to your specific code, where is `o` (from `o.cookies`) coming from, and why is it expected to be a boolean?

Side note: almost all code can benefit from properly-named variables. Letting your minifier reduce down to single-letter will keep your code more readable.

Comment: Is is just a var. From for the plugin. Thanks for the tip. But do you know how to retrieve the value of a cookie without an offical plugin

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. But I would look at the official plugin or someone else's sample, modify if need be and move it into my application. It would take up the same amount of space or less compared to writing my own from scratch. Plugins or results from a web search are no different than someone here answering your question with a code sample. You're migrating someone else's code and making good use of it either way. ;-)

Comment: Thanks I got the code to work. I just need to use the $.getCookie() function and it worked fine. Thanks for the help.